# Sending "Authentication Required Message" when not authenticated and "Session has expired" when session is timed out

Tags: session, jsf-2, primefaces

i am working with login filters and have implemented them successfully . but right now , i need to show an error message saying "Authentication Required" if user tries to view a page , by giving (the page's URL) directly in the address bar .

Also i need to show an error message like "Session has expired" , when the session is timed out .
The implementation for the latter (as suggested by everyone) ,  redirecting to login or index.xhtml using the filters ,  is over . But i thought of showing the error message .

any help ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: post what you have tried a

Comment: hi makky , i have hit the web.xml file and specified the error page , exception type (View expired exception) like many others .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23217445/1453701
In your case instead of using flash or session scope, you should use url parameters to let the view know that it should add a FacesMessage in @PostConstruct

In your bean you can put:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    String showMessage = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("showMessage");
    if ("true".equals(showMessage)) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Authentication Required", "place your detailed message here"));
    }
}
```

Comment: hi tushee , thanks for your response . But since im new to jsf can u show some piece of code to add facesMessage in @postconstruct and using url parameters

Comment: I've edited my answer with example @PostConstruct method

Comment: as you said ,, when session expires , i am appending the following httpResponse.sendRedirect(httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml?showMessage=true") in the servlet filter, but in my bean , when i accessed that value using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("showMessage") , the value stored in the string showMessage is null !! any idea ?

Comment: After the redirect, do you see the request parameter in the url?

Comment: sorry tushee , i made a small mistake in servlet filter . Now i corrected it . Thanks for  your answer . It got worked !

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like onload check for the page body, which calls a remotecommand. In the remotecommand's action itself, you can specify the Bean method that does the check:

```
<h:body  id="page_body"  onload="isConnected();">
    <h:form >
        <p:remoteCommand name="isConnected" update=":page_body" autoRun="false" action="#{myBean.checkIfLoggedIn()}"/>
    </h:form>
    ..................
</h:body>
```