# Show FacesMessage and reload Page in JSF

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am sending Emails From a JSF Application. I need it Such That When I Send the Email, a FacesMessage is Displayed Confirming the Action and the Browser reloads to the Same Page. The code I have Shows the Face but does Not reload the same page.

```
public String sendEmail(){
//Email Sending Code.....
 Transport.send(message);

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                    "Successfull\n", "You have successfully sent an e-mail to : " + e_mail + ". \n Thank You"));

            return "Email?redirect-true";
}
```

This is What I Have tried, this code Reloads the Page But the FacesMessage is Not Shown.

```
public String sendEmail(){
    //Email Sending Code.....
     Transport.send(message);

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                        "Successfull\n", "You have successfully sent an e-mail to : " + e_mail + ". \n Thank You"));
                 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpServletRequest origRequest = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
            String contextPath = origRequest.getContextPath();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(contextPath + "/faces/Email.xhtml");
                return "Email?redirect-true";
    }
```

And Here Is My Code for the Send Email Page:

```
    <h:form >
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>
            <p:panel header="Send Email" style=" width: 70%">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 
                    <h:outputLabel value="E Mail Address: " />
                    <h:inputText value="#{mailing.e_mail}" style="width: 400px"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Subject: " /> 
                    <h:inputText value="#{mailing.subject}" style="width: 400px"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Message: " />
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{mailing.mess}" style="height: 300px;width: 700px"/>
                    <h:panelGroup/>
                    <p:commandButton
                        value="Send Mail "
                        action="#{mailing.sendEmail()}"
                        ajax="false"/>
                </h:panelGrid> 
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
```

Please help

Comment: Post the relevant part of the jsf page

Comment: I have Just Updated With My Send Email Page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set [`keepMessages` to `true`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#isKeepMessages%28%29) on the [`Flash`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/Flash.html) object if you want to preserve `FacesMessages` across a redirect. The `Flash` scope is a new scope introduced in JSF2. The scope (and the accompanying implicit EL object `flash`) is intended for **short term** storage of "stuff" (meaning anything you want to keep, for a short period).

Try the following line before you redirect:

```
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

The line above sets the necessary flag to ensure your message is preserved.

Further Reading:

- [Max Katz's JSF Blog on Flash](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/)

Answer (score -1):

You can't add FacesMessage to the next view. After redirecting a new view will be created, with a new FacesContext where the messages is an empty list. If you follow this mechanism step-by-step you can see that there is no way to do this:

1. Request get hit on server, JSF servlet **creates a new FacesContext**, wraps the request into a RequestContext, enters the JSF lifecycle
2. JSF restores the current view, applies the request, does the validation, updates the models, invoke your application code (which will send a redirect), renders the response (which contains only the redirect)
3. Browsers redirects to the new view
4. Request get hit on server, JSF servlet **creates a new FacesContext**, wraps the request into a RequestContext, enters the JSF lifecycle
5. JSF creates a new view and renders the response.

If you want to add message on page load, you should store something about it in a scope which survives the redirect (e.g. flash, session) and add your FacesMessage in your new view's bean's @PostConstruct method.