# Show FacesMessage after redirection from servlet or JAX-RS using Flash

Tags: jsf-2

I want to implement activation link via servlet or JAX-RS (not important which one), and later redirect user to proper page leaving him a FacesMessage stored in Flash. I have no problem with redirection itself, however I don't know how to access Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain access to the `Flash` object from the `ExternalContext`:

1. Obtain access to the `Flash`:

   ```
   Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
   ```
2. Set `keepMessages =true` on the object, to ensure that the `FacesMessage` you store in it survives the redirect

   ```
   flash.setKeepMessages(true);
   ```
3. Store your `FacesMessages` using the `putNow` method, to ensure that even after the redirect, the messages will survive at least one page refresh

   ```
   flash.putNow(yourFacesMessage);
   ```

You really don't need to store the `FacesMessage` in the flash object itself; queuing them in the `FacesContext` is enough to guarantee that they'll be available on the other page

Related:

- [Show FacesMessage and reload Page in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216155/show-facesmessage-and-reload-page-in-jsf/23226428#23226428)

Comment: are you sure it should work in servlet? I get NPE at `ExternalContext ec = facesContext.getExternalContext();`. `facesContext` obtained with `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();`

Comment: @Guest your question is not clear in that regard; you should've stated that you were trying to retrieve the `Flash` object within a servlet. In which case, I'd advise against it. Just store the messages as request attributes and retrieve in the destination backing bean. If you insist on the flash object use [this tutorial](http://myfaces.apache.org/wiki/core/user-guide/jsf-and-myfaces-howtos/backend/access-facescontext-from-servlet.html) to retrieve the `FacesContext` and get the Flash object